# How to delete a pod in Unknown state in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a kubernetes cluster on Amazon EKS and from time to time there appear some pods with the state `Unknown`. I read that this is because my pods have no memory limits set and after changing that no new pods with that state have appeared. But I tried to remove the existing ones using `kubectl delete pod <pod_name>` and it didn't work. How should I delete them?

Comment: Did you figure out if it might relate to a certain Node? Check if you can see if there is a correlation to specific nodes "kubectl get pods -o wide | grep Unknown"
What gives you the describe outpud? kubectl describe pod <pod_name>?

Comment: It seems it is related to one node. kubectl describe gives me something interesting: 

Status:                    Terminating (lasts 1d)
Termination Grace Period:  30s
Reason:                    NodeLost

Comment: Check on the memory limit of this node. And the overall health status of this node.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can force delete the pod like this:

```
kubectl delete pod <pod_name> --grace-period=0 --force
```

Comment: sometimes not work and need: `patch pod  -p '{"metadata":{"finalizers":null}}'`

Answer (score 3):

In a Kubernetes cluster one can create Pod using Kubernetes Workload. There are Workloads of following kinds:

- Deployment
- ReplicaSet
- DaemonSet
- StatefulSet
- ReplicationController
- Job
- CronJob
- Or Pod (directly)

If you use any of the above list other than Pod, then the Pod's ownerReference (`.metadata.ownerRefference`) is set for that Pod. Say, If you create a Deployment named `d1`, then it first create a ReplicaSet named `d1-***` in which case the ownerRefference for the ReplicaSet is the Deployment `d1`. Then the ReplicaSet will create a number of Pod(s) (with prefix `d1-***-***`). So the Pod's ownerRefference will be the ReplicaSet `d1-***`.

- If you just delete the Pods create by a Deployment, then the Pods will be deleted. But they are again recreated by the owner ReplicaSet.
- If you just delete the ReplicaSet, then the ReplicaSet and it's Pods will be deleted. But the Deployment controller will again recreate the ReplicaSet and then the newly created ReplicaSet will create Pods again.
- But if you just delete the original Deployment, then everything for it will be deleted too.

---

**UPDATE:**

If you don't want to delete your original Deployment or other Workload due to keep the prod up, then you will be able to accomplish your want by force deleting the Pod:

```
 $ kubectl delete pod <pod_name> --namespace <namespace> --grace-period 0 --force
```

According to the `kubectl` command reference,

- **`--grace-period`:** Default is `-1`. Period of time in seconds given to the resource to terminate gracefully. Ignored if negative. Set to 1 for immediate shutdown. Can only be set to 0 when --force is true (force deletion).
- **`--force`:*** Default is `false`. Only used when grace-period=0. If true, immediately remove resources from API and bypass graceful deletion. Note that immediate deletion of some resources may result in inconsistency or data loss and requires confirmation.

That's the case for you.

Comment: I don't want to delete deployment because it would also delete working pods.

Comment: @KarolSamborski So the others are right. Since you are using the Deployment in production, deleting the original Deployment is not a wise thing. In that case you just need to force delete the Pods. But the main thing is you should make your problem description quite clear by providing enough info (what you want, what you did, what you got like these kind of things).

Answer (score 0):

did you directly deploy the pod?
or is it deployed from deployment or statefulset?
try delete the deployment or statefulset.

if nothing works out then delete the namespace the pod is in. But all objects get deleted from that namespace

Comment: It's deployed from deployment. Kubernetes knows that these pods are not active so it launched another instances. But if I delete deployment all of them will be gone and it means our production would need to stop working for some (short) time.

Comment: did you try ```kubectl delete pod NAME --grace-period=0 --force``` ?

Comment: @KrishnaGangaraju no until now and this actually worked! please post it as answer and I will accept it. Thanks!